# My jasig don't use the User ldap password

Tags: ssl, single-sign-on, jasig

We have several services auntentican with an LDAP server, we put JASIG as the main entrance, we deploy JASIG on Jboss7 and works well over SSL, however our LDAP server over TLS works. My problem is that over TLS for any authenticated user runs any user password, right or wrong.

I do not know why the login username is sensitive and not sensitive to the password, pass any password.

Thank you.

Show parts interesting parts of my DeployConfigContex.xml file.

**This is our AuthenticationManager:**

```
    <bean id="authenticationManager" 
            class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">                
            <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
                    <list>                

                            <bean 

                                    class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.CredentialsToLDAPAttributePrincipalResolver">


                                    <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolver">
                                            <bean 
                                                    class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" />
                                    </property>

                                    <property name="filter" value="(cn=%u)" />
                                    <property name="principalAttributeName" value="cn" />
                                    <property name="searchBase" value="ou=ServiciosCentrales,ou=Usuarios,dc=educacion,dc=es" />
                                    <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />

                                    <property name="attributeRepository">
                                            <ref bean="attributeRepository" />
                                    </property>

                            </bean>                

                    </list>
            </property>
            <property name="authenticationHandlers">
                    <list>
                            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler" 
                                    p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" />                                
                            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler">
                              <property name="filter" value="cn=%u" />
                              <property name="searchBase" value="ou=ServiciosCentrales,ou=Usuarios,dc=educacion,dc=es" />
                              <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />
                              <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="yes" />  
                            </bean>                                                                                                          
                    </list>
            </property>

    </bean>
```

**this es our contexsource:**

```
            <property name="pooled" value="false" />

            <property name="userDn" value="cn=secret,dc=educacion,dc=es"/>
            <property name="password" value="secret"/>


            <property name="url" value="ldap://192.168.0.100:389"/>             
            <qualifier value="secured"/>                                

            <property name="authenticationStrategy">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy">
                            <property name="sslSocketFactory">
                                    <bean class="com.cein.educa.ldap.LDAPSocketFactory" />
                            </property>  
                            <property name="hostnameVerifier">
                                    <bean class="com.cein.educa.ldap.LDAPHostNameVerifier" />
                            </property>  

                            <property name="shutdownTlsGracefully" value="true" />
                    </bean>
            </property>

    <property name="baseEnvironmentProperties">                
                    <map>  
                            <entry key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
                    </map>  
            </property>                                

    </bean>
```